# Link pre-installed apps to Homebrew Cask

Tags: homebrew, macos

I installed Slack by downloading the DMG from its website and copying the app bundle into `/Applications` directory. Alternatively, I could have used `brew cask install slack`.

Is there a way to make Homebrew aware of this drag-and-drop version of Slack ? Or do I need to remove it and install via `brew cask` in order for it to be detected by Homebrew?

Answer (score 8):

In versions `2.0.5` and above, it seems you can make Homebrew reinstall the Mac app by applying the `--force` flag:

```
brew install --cask --force slack
```

Answer (score 4):

I have found the best way to fix this issue is `brew cask reinstall <cask>`. Homebrew then removes the old version as if it installed it and the new version is now managed. That for me has been the cleanest solution.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work now (April 2019). Though the method listed below, i.e. `brew cask install --force` works.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, there is not way to update the Homebrew Cask database with the pre-installed apps.

If you wish to have an app installed via Homebrew (so that it gets listed when running `brew list --cask`), you'll need to remove the downloaded and installed version from the `/Applications` directory, and install via Homebrew.

Comment: `brew cask list` shows apps that have *already* been installed with Cask. To see if an application is available within `cask`, use `brew search [app-name]` and look under the `==> Casks` header. You can see more info about specific casks by using `brew cask info [cask-name]` (note that the specified name must exactly match the cask's for this command).

Comment: @aaplmath My bad. Thanks for the information. I was aware of the same but wrote an incorrectly worded statement. I have edited to fix it. Please feel free to edit the answer if you find it lacking.

Answer (score 0):

In homebrew versions 3.0.4 and above, you can force the installation of a brew cask like this:

```
brew install --cask spotify --force
```

Note that some apps (like Spotify) may require you to authenticate as sudo during the installation to overwrite some of the files in the Applications folder.